# How to handle popup window by using WinAppDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, winapp

While automating a desktop application we have multiple popup windows. i have tried  all Winapp methods to switch the focus to that popup but unable to get the focus ,and unable to locate the elements which are available in that popup window

is there a way to handle such type of popup window using Winapp driver